# What is the best method to bin intraday volume figures from a stock price timeseries using XTS / ZOO etc in R?

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo, quantitative-finance

For instance, let's say you have ~10 years of daily 1 min data for the volume of instrument x as follows (in `xts` format) from 9:30am to 4:30pm :

```
    Date.Time               Volume        
    2001-01-01 09:30:00     1200
    2001-01-01 09:31:00     1110
    2001-01-01 09:32:00     1303
```

All the way through to:

```
    2010-12-20 16:28:00     3200
    2010-12-20 16:29:00     4210
    2010-12-20 16:30:00     8303
```

I would like to:

- Get the average volume at each minute for the entire series (ie average volume over all 10 years at 9:30, 9:31, 9:32...16:28, 16:29, 16:30)

How should I best go about:

- Aggregating the data into one minute buckets
- Getting the average of those buckets
- Reconstituting those "average" buckets back to a single xts/zoo time series?

I've had a good poke around with `aggregate`, `sapply`, `period.apply` functions etc, but just cannot seem to "bin" the data correctly.

It's easy enough to solve this with a loop, but very slow. I'd prefer to avoid a programmatic solution and use a function that takes advantage of C++ architecture (ie `xts` based solution)

Can anyone offer some advice / a solution?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First lets create some test data:

```
library(xts) # also pulls in zoo
library(timeDate)
library(chron) # includes times class

# test data
x <- xts(1:3, timeDate(c("2001-01-01 09:30:00", "2001-01-01 09:31:00", 
    "2001-01-02 09:30:00")))
```

**1) aggregate.zoo**. Now try converting it to `times` class and aggregating using this one-liner:

```
aggregate(as.zoo(x), times(format(time(x), "%H:%M:%S")), mean)
```

**1a) aggregate.zoo (variation)**. or this variation which converts the shorter aggregate series to `times` to avoid having to do it on the longer original series:

```
ag <- aggregate(as.zoo(x), format(time(x), "%H:%M:%S"), mean)
zoo(coredata(ag), times(time(ag)))
```

**2) tapply**. An alternative would be `tapply` which is likely faster:

```
ta <- tapply(coredata(x), format(time(x), "%H:%M:%S"), mean)
zoo(unname(ta), times(names(ta)))
```

EDIT: simplified (1) and added (1a) and (2)

Comment: Thank you for posting this very elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `ddply`,
but you can probably also use `sqldf`, `tapply`, `aggregate`, `by`, etc.

```
# Sample data
minutes <- 10 * 60
days <- 250 * 10
d <- seq.POSIXt( 
  ISOdatetime( 2011,01,01,09,00,00, "UTC" ), 
  by="1 min", length=minutes 
)
d <- outer( d, (1:days) * 24*3600, `+` )
d <- sort(d)
library(xts)
d <- xts( round(100*rlnorm(length(d))), d )

# Aggregate
library(plyr)
d <- data.frame( 
  minute=format(index(d), "%H:%M"), 
  value=coredata(d) 
)
d <- ddply( 
  d, "minute", 
  summarize, 
  value=mean(value, na.rm=TRUE) 
)

# Convert to zoo or xts
zoo(x=d$value, order.by=d$minute) # The index does not have to be a date or time
xts(x=d$value, order.by=as.POSIXct(sprintf("2012-01-01 %s:00",d$minute), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") )
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had `sqldf` in mind, but it seemed like a "cheat" for what I was trying to achieve.

Now to your code.

This is working well up to the use of `ddply` (ie, i've built the data frame with minute and value (structured as chr and num respectively). However, it just returns "NA" for the (mean) value column.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry - I should state that your model code works fine throughout. It is not, however, working on my data.

a `str()` call on the volume data returns: num [1:976638, 1] 46 32 24 7 34 27 9 18 2 24 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "Volume" ///

and the `index` of my data:

Formal class 'timeDate' [package "fCalendar"] with 3 slots
  ..@ Data     : POSIXct[1:976638], format: "2001-07-02 09:51:00" "2001-07-02 09:52:00" "2001-07-02 09:53:00" "2001-07-02 09:54:00" ...
  ..@ format   : chr "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

Comment: The error being returned in my adaptation is: In mean.default(value, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: I tried to use `timeDate` objects for the index
(`library(timeDate);
d <- seq(Sys.timeDate(), by=60, length=10);
d <- xts(...)`),
but it works fine. However, your `timeDate` objects seem to come 
from the obsolete `fCalendar` package: it has been replaced with `timeDate`.